# What is the equivalent of std::thread::join in QThread C++

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5, qthread, stdthread

How can I wait for the finish of a `QThread` or What is the equivalent of `std::thread::join()` method in `QThread`

In std::thread,  I can do it like the following

```cpp
void foo()
{
    // simulate expensive operation
    std::cout << "starting first thread1...\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

void bar()
{
    // simulate expensive operation
    std::cout << "starting second thread2...\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

int main()
{

    std::thread thread1(foo);


    std::thread thread2(bar);

    
    std::cout << "waiting for threads to finish..." << std::endl;
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    std::cout << "done!\n";
}
```

The output gives the following output:

```
starting first thread1...
waiting for threads to finish...
starting second thread2...
done!
```

Comment: `QThread::wait`

Comment: Yes, I agree with @AlexF. Wait method makes the principal thread waiting until the thread which is linked to `wait` has ended, whether it's has reached the end or not of its execution. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait

Comment: Please don't pu answers in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @[Alex F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279313/alex-f) for your suggestion.

Here is what I tried then:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>

#include <QThread>

#include "mydialog.h"

#include <QDebug>

 

void foo()

{

    // simulkate a long work

    qDebug() << " Starting Qthread1 ..." ;

    QThread::msleep(5000);

}

 

void bar()

{

    qDebug() << " Starting Qthread2 ..." ;

    QThread::msleep(2000);

}

 

 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

 

    QThread* thread1 = QThread::create(foo);

    QThread* thread2 = QThread::create(bar);

 

    // to verify at real-time when the thread finishes

    QObject::connect(thread1, &QThread::finished, [](){ qDebug()<< "Thread1 has finished";});

    QObject::connect(thread2, &QThread::finished, [](){ qDebug()<< "Thread2 has finished";});

 

    thread1->start();

    thread2->start();

 

    qDebug()<< "Waiting for threads to finish";

    thread1->wait();

    thread2->wait();

 

    qDebug() << "done";

 

    return a.exec();

}
```

The output is as follows:

```sh
Waiting for threads to finish
  Starting QThread2 ...
  Strating QThread1 ...
Thread 2 has finished 
Thread 1 has finished
```